# Customize Jenkins Stop [x] button function

Tags: jenkins, abort

My Jenkins builds spawn a number of jobs that it doesn't have visibility over.

If I abort a build by pressing the stop button, the jobs continue until I start a new build which deletes the workspace causing all the jobs to fall over because there directory no longer exists.

This is not ideal, so I'm wondering if it's possible to add some functionality to the stop button to kill those jobs?

Note, I am referring to  [**this button**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Aborting+a+build)

Comment: How exactly do you „_spawn_“ the „_number of jobs_“?

Comment: I have a bash script that starts off a series of jobs using bsub (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.2/lsf_command_ref/bsub.1.dita)

If the build runs to completion everything gets tidied up nicely. If it is interrupted, it leaves a bit of a mess.

Comment: It would have been advantagous if you had mentioned that these jobs are external jobs. ;) See [my second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33374078/1744774).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With external jobs (which, BTW, can be monitored with the job type [External Job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs)) you can do the following:

- Create a [parameterized](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) Freestyle job.
- Configure the build no. to be entered as parameter, e.g. `NUMBER_OF_BUILD_TO_ABORT`, at job start.
- Add an *Execute shell* or an *Execute Groovy script* *Build step* that contains:

  ```
   
  ... code to kill the external jobs ...

  ... code that calls http://jenkins/job/<job name>/${NUMBER_OF_BUILD_TO_ABORT}/stop ...
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I just created:

- A [Freestyle](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) project with **Build** →  **Execute shell** → Command:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  while true
  do
    echo "  SO-33348825-sub-1 running eternally..."
    sleep 10
  done
  ```
- A [Workflow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin) project with **Workflow** → Definition → Script:

  ```
  println("  SO-33348825-main-workflow started")
  build("SO-33348825-sub-1")
  println("  SO-33348825-main-workflow ended")
  ```

Log of *SO-33348825-main-workflow* after starting and aborting it:

```
...
  SO-33348825-main-workflow started
Running: Building SO-33348825-sub-1
Starting building project: SO-33348825-sub-1
Aborted by anonymous
Running: End of Workflow
java.lang.Exception: ABORTED
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerListener.onCompleted(BuildTriggerListener.java:20)
    at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireCompleted(RunListener.java:201)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1786)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Finished: ABORTED
```

Log of *SO-33348825-sub-1* after starting and aborting *SO-33348825-main-workflow*:

```
Started by upstream project "SO-33348825-main-workflow" build number 1
...
[workspace] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson1610853144078403465.sh
  SO-33348825-sub-1 running eternally...
  SO-33348825-sub-1 running eternally...
  SO-33348825-sub-1 running eternally...
Build was aborted
Calling workflow was cancelled
...
Finished: ABORTED
```

#### Conclusion

Builds started by a Workflow project are aborted if the Workflow build is aborted.